# Error:(45) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) Because Button "<<"

Tags: java, android, xml

I Have a Button android studio, this is my code :

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="40dp"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:background="@color/colorAccent"
   android:text=" << "
   android:textColor="@color/colorText" />
```

When i run this project, Then it shows a code error. Here is the code error :

> Error:(45) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

**But when i change the android text button**

```
android:text="<<"
```

**I change it to the following code, my project can run well**

```
android:text="Button"
```

**The question is how to make a button android studio but use text value "<<" ? thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the "<" characters

```
android:text="&lt;&lt;"
```

"<" is a special character in XML.

http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000005870

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape each `<`, as following:

```
android:text="&lt;&lt;"
```

To understand different escape characters, see this post : [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)